# Download popup not coming properly in asp.net page load

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to open the file based on the below code.

I am not using server.mappath. because, the access path is direct file server path and it is mapped with service account.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string filePath1 = @"\\RMN\T001\PROC\MATERIALDB\";
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "MAT01210821.png");
Response.WriteFile(filePath1);
Response.ContentType = "";
Response.End();
}
```

I am getting below error.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

My requirement is, when i execute the above code, it should ask popup to end user "Do you want to open or save the file ..."? below screenshot for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGl4B.png)

Comment: Where are you getting that error? What is the *actual* error? Trying to load a file from an invalid or non-existent path has nothing to do with the browser's download dialog.

Comment: You're trying to send a *folder* to the browser, not the actual path. Rename `filePath1` to `folder` to avoid confusion and use `Path.Combine(folder, "MAT01210821.png") ` to generate the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the actual error is missing, the line `Response.WriteFile(filePath1);` is trying to use a *folder* as if it was a file.

To avoid such confusion, the folder path should be stored in a variable named `folder` and used to construct the actual path.

```
var folder = @"\\RMN\T001\PROC\MATERIALDB\";
var fileName="MAT01210821.png";
var filePath=Path.Combine(folder, fileName) ;
...
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

Comment: The end user doesn't see the full `filePath`, only the `filename` attribute which can be whatever you want. `How it is possible..?` does the file contain anything?

Comment: Thank you very much a lot..it's working now.  finally i used Transmitfile and using contenttype as "application/pdf" with the above code.
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath); 
            response.End();